# Correct way to update nested object with Mapstruct

Tags: mapstruct

I am using mapstruct to update a user object, so I have something like a JPA entity as my target ..

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String userName;
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USERPROFILEID")
    private UserProfile userProfile;
...}
```

and then a DTO as my source..

```
public class UserDto {

    Integer id;
    String userName;
    UserProfile userProfile;
...}
```

and then my mapper interface ...

```
@Mapper(componentModel = MappingConstants.ComponentModel.SPRING,
        nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE)
public interface UserMapper {
      void updateUserFromDto(@MappingTarget User user, UserDto dto);
...}
```

If I replace the user profile object on my DTO with a userProfileDto, then mapstruct will try and copy over each of the properties from my DTO to the userprofile entity on my target. What I want is to just take the new userprofile entity and copy that over, so it currently works but is this the correct way to just swap out an entity ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, you would like in the `UserDto` to set the new user profile for that particular user. If I was in your case then instead of using `UserProfileDto` in the `UserDto` I would use a `String` for representing the id of the user profile you would like to set on the user.

e.g.

```java
public class UserDto {

    Integer id;
    String userName;
    String userProfile;
...}
```

Then in the mapping you can provide a custom mapping from `String` to `UserProfile`

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = MappingConstants.ComponentModel.SPRING,
        nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE, uses = UserProfileMapper.class)
public interface UserMapper {

      void updateUserFromDto(@MappingTarget User user, UserDto dto);
...}

@Component
public class UserProfileMapper {

    protected final UserProfileRepository userProfileRepository;

    public UserProfile findUserProfileById(String userProfileId) {
        return userProfileId == null ? null : userProfileRepository.findById(userProfileId);
    }

}
```